# How to resize container height based on browser width

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

How can I scale the black containers height from max-height of 550px to for example height of 400px by just changing browsers width. And together with the black container the box divs also should get smaller proportionally. I want it without the use of media queries.. I want it to change dynamically so you can see it resizing pixel by pixel. I don't want it to just jump from one height to another by reaching a media queries width.

```css
.container-black {
    height: 550px;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: solid 8px grey;
}

.box1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70%;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="container-black">
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: use media queries ?

Comment: just use css media queries or you can use vh / vw as sizing unit ( like- height : 90 vh ).

Comment: without the use of media queries.. I want it to change dynamically so you can see it resizing pixel by pixel. I don't want it to just jump from one height to another by reaching a media queries width.

Comment: @Kikoanno So you're saying when you re-size your browser vertically you want the height to be dynamic and change with it, without media queries? The height of an element won't change when resizing horizontally unless you use media queries. If anything, it will only increase vertically when resizing browser width so the elements still fit on small devices.

Comment: @Kameron The result I want to achieve can be seen in Netflix landing page if you are signed out of your account. The black containers have max height values and it gets smaller and smaller pixel by pixel with all its divs when you resize the browsers width.

Comment: @Kikoanno see my adjusted answer. You have to use a `container` that has a `100vw` and set each `container-black` to 33% height. So the heights will adjust based of percentages of available screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dynamic values such as `vw` or viewport width. For example, to keep your black borders you can set `box1` to `width: 40vw;`. This means `box1` will use 40% of the viewport size when resizing, and the `container-black` will maintain 10% of viewport width on any device. Allowing it to be responsive.

> The Dynamic Viewport is the viewport sized with *dynamic consideration of any UA interfaces*. It will automatically adjust itself in response to UA interface elements being shown or not

- [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/the-large-small-and-dynamic-viewports/)

**EDIT** -- added 2 more `container-blacks` and nested them in parent container and defined their height based of `%` so that they resize responsively.

```css
.container-black {
    height: 33%;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: solid 8px grey;
}

.box1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70%;
    width: 40vw;
    background-color: red;
}

.container {
  height: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="container-black">
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="container-black">
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <div class="container-black">
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Assumenda libero quidem minima tenetur delectus,
                iusto hic perferendis repudiandae soluta maxime nemo facere rem vero officiis! Illo deserunt eum ullam
                eligendi!</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vw` unit (= percent of viewport width) in your `height` definition, if necessary, inside a media query

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using `vw` unit on the height of the black box.

1vw equals 1% of the viewport's width.

Another way is the CSS aspect-ratio feature. You can learn more in the link below.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/